# Jest SpyOn value instead of getter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have a function like this:

```
class MyClass

    constructor(private readonly simpleInstance: SomeOtherClass) {}

    get myGetter() {
        if(!simpleInstance) {
            throw Error('Bad thing')
        }
        return simpleIntance.id
    }
```

I want to write a test case where `simpleInstance = null`

I am having alot of trouble mocking out `simpleInstance`

Here is my test so far, and a few options that I have tried.

> Note: I am using `NestJs` so there is a dependency injection pattern within my tests which I have removed for brevity. **TL;DR**: an initialized `SomeOtherClass` gets passed into `MyClass` during instantiation.

```
describe('MyClass', () => {
    let myClassInstance: MyClass
    let someOtherClassMock: jest.Mock<SomeOtherClass>

    beforeEach(() => {
        someOtherClassMock = jest.fn()
        myClassInstance = new MyClass(someOtherClassMock)
    })

    it('should throw an error if injected simpleInstance is null', () => {
      userMock = ........ // <--- Setting up the mocked value is where I have trouble
      expect(() => myClassInstance.myGetter).toThrow(Error('Bad thing'))
    })
})
```

I have tried returning mocked values, spying on `someOtherClassMock` and returning a value, etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why not just call `myClassInstance = new MyClass(null)` in your `it` test case?

Comment: You can make that an answer if you want as that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a mock is not necessary. You can simply explicitly create your instance with `null` for its parameter of `SomeOtherClass` in your `it` test case:

```
it('should throw an error if injected simpleInstance is null', () => {
  myClassInstance = new MyClass(null)
  expect(() => myClassInstance.myGetter).toThrow(Error('Bad thing'))
})
```